# ¿Cómo ejecutar comandos desde PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, cmd

Necesito obtener el número serial de la BIOS desde Oracle database, lo logre con el uso del comando HOST pero este no me permite manipular el dato, ya cree una libreria de java sin embargo no me muestra nada, solo cuando ejecuto el comando dir dentro eso si me devuelve valores, espero puedan ayudarme:(

select hostcommfunc('dir C:\Users') from dual; --esto si me devuelve valores

Comment: Pero será el BIOS del computador donde reside la base de datos.

Comment: Si es esa BIOS, necesito poder manipular el dato desde oracle